# how to pick string and Concatenate from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have data like this

```
declare @t table (Id int,val varchar(200),ad varchar(100))

insert into @t (Id,val,ad)values (1,'D:\Documents\FranchiseeUpload\Caste\CGC011400000192\01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jun.pdf','01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jul.pdf'),
(1,'D:\Documents\FranchiseeUpload\Caste\CGC011400000193\01~CNM_Anx3.pdf 01~CNM_Anx3.pdf','01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jul.pdf')

select * from @t
```

i just want to pick the last '\' and from their in need to add data from another column

output :

```
Id  val ad

    1   D:\Documents\FranchiseeUpload\Caste\CGC011400000192\01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jul.pdf    01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jul.pdf
    1   D:\Documents\FranchiseeUpload\Caste\CGC011400000193\01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jul.pdf    01~HYD TO BBS 11 Jul.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `LEFT()`, `CHARINDEX()`, `LEN()` and `REVERSE()` functions:

```
SELECT id, 
       LEFT(val, LEN(val) -CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(val), 0) + 1) + ad As Val, 
       ad
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Find the chars after last `'/'` and replace it with `ad` column.

```
SELECT id , 
Replace(val, 
        REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(val),0,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(val)))), 
       ad) AS val, 
Ad 
from @t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:

```
SELECT
    id,
    STUFF(val, LEN(Val) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(val)) + 2, LEN(Val), '') + ad,
    ad
FROM
    @t
```

Answer (score 0):

CHARINDEX can search for a string, but only from the start.  So, if you reverse your string first, it's similar to searching from the end.

Then you just take the appropriate left most part of the string, and concatenate your other field.

```
SELECT
    id,
    CONCAT(
        LEFT(val, LEN(val) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(val))),
        '\',
        ad
    ),
    ad
FROM
    @t
```

Note that if there is no `\` in your first field, then this will just append a `\` to the end of it, and then add the `ad` field after that.